# Optimization for specific processor

Tags: c, optimization, assembly

I am new in optimization and need some explanation...

For example I have next programm:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        __asm {
                push esi
                push edi

                inc ebx
                inc eax
                mov ebx, 0xffffffff
                mov eax, 0xaaaaaaaa

                pop edi
                pop esi
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So when i do in vtune test - "Advanced Hotspot Analysis". I get that in function main this is alwayws some hotspots:

```
Address Source Line Assembly    CPU Time: Total by Utilization  CPU Time: Self by Utilization   Instructions Retired: Total Instructions Retired: Self  Overhead and Spin Time: Total   Overhead and Spin Time: Self    Wait Time: Total    Wait Time: Self Inactive Time: Total    Inactive Time: Self
0x401000        Block 1:            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401000    1   push ebx            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401001    1   push esi            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401002    1   push edi            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401003    3   mov ecx, 0x1e8480           0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401008        Block 2:            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401008    5   push esi    0ms 0ms 62.3%   14,956,555  0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms
0x401009    6   push edi    0.872ms 0.872ms 0.5%    116,752 0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms
0x40100a    8   inc ebx         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40100b    9   inc eax         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40100c    10  mov ebx, 0xffffffff         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401011    11  mov eax, 0xaaaaaaaa         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401016    13  pop edi         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401017    14  pop esi 2.923ms 2.923ms 20.6%   4,950,489   0.0%    0ms 8.5%    0.007ms 0.0%    0ms
0x401018    4   dec ecx 0.872ms 0.872ms 6.7%    1,613,429   0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms 0.0%    0ms
0x401019    4   jnz 0x401008 <Block 2>          0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40101b        Block 3:            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40101b    19  pop edi         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40101c    19  pop esi         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40101d    19  xor eax, eax            0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x40101f    19  pop ebx         0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%    
0x401020    19  ret             0.0%        0.0%        0.0%        0.0%
```

As I understand all instruction is pairing and this is not be any problem with decoding of push/pop instructon...
So why do hotspots appear and can O remove them for some specific proceesor (f.e. i7)?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Inserting arbitrary, pointless memory access will do that to you :)

Comment: The obvious optimization is to remove all the no-ops, leaving you with  `int main() { return 0; }`

Comment: I added that inline just for test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this level, hotspot analysis might not point to the exact instruction that's responsible for most of the performance hit for a given basic block.  One instruction can stall for a long time due to exhaustion of resources that started getting depleted many instructions back.  For example, you might be running out of load buffers due to the `mov`s that lead to old copies of rename registers for `eax` and `ebx` hanging around longer than ideal, which in turn leads to stalling on the `push`es and `pop`s.  Or it could have to do with pipeline bubbles from branch prediction of the preceding `jnz`.

Any of that is speculation though.  Choosing a VTune analysis type that exposes front-end and back-end stalls might help.  Like twalberg says though, this analysis and any further would be more meaningful on code that accomplishes real work.

If your goal was ultimately to improve total running time, there are plenty of other techniques you could apply.  In particular, you know at compile time how many times your loop is going to execute and can say for sure that there are no dependencies between iterations.  In these circumstances unrolling and vectorization are trivial.  Compare the output you get here to the instructions used when compiling similar C code with flags something like "-O3 -mtune=corei7".  You will probably see no loop body at all since all work up until the last iteration is thrown out, but if you tweak it enough to trick the compiler into thinking it needs to generate code for each time through, you still might see more efficient instructions being used.

Answer (score 0):

This smells a lot like premature optimization. The reality is that optimization is not about completely removing hotspots, but more about reducing the impact of certain critical code path hot spots. In this particular example, there is no way to avoid the fact that each of the asm instructions will be executed a certain number of times, and the reality is that some instructions, by nature of what they do, just naturally take longer to execute on certain platforms. The PUSH/POP instructions write and read to memory and update a register, along with certain bounds checks, etc. The INC and MOV instructions simply update a register (once you've been through the loop once, the immediate operands to the MOV instructions are in the instruction cache, and the loop is small enough they won't be evicted, so the instruction fetch/decode overhead on all the instructions is not a major factor). The cache and memory cycles of the PUSH/POP operations mean that they take measurably longer to execute that the INC/MOV operations, and will thus appear to take the significant portion of the execution time.

If you want to avoid the execution time taken by the PUSH/POP instructions, you could 1) eliminate the PUSH/POP instructions, since they don't accomplish anything anyway, but then the other instructions will appear to take the bulk of the execution time, or 2) introduce other instructions that "spread the load around", or 3) try your hand at optimizing something real, not a tiny example that really does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But than I look for some another function from real code and it looks that generally compiler generate good code...